# Ideas for physics for rolling dice

Tags: android, algorithm, graphics

I want to make rolling cube like dice that reacts on accelerometer. So accelerometer gives parameters for cube moving. I think that small physic should be used here. My question is what formulas, techniques should I use to accomplish this without any physics engine.

Comment: "Dice" is already plural. One die, many dice.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad / tool rec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need probably to use OpenGL for that. There a good physics tutorial for [OGL here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=39)

Specifically for dice, take a look at this [nokia demo](http://projects.forum.nokia.com/gles2phys). It's written in cpp ([source here](https://projects.forum.nokia.com/gles2phys/files))

On the physics side, you can take a look at [this site](http://dicephysics.info/).

Anyhow, I do not think you need *real* physics for the app, but just an approximation:

- I would start getting a velocity that depends on the accelerometer (plus or minus, let's say, 20%) and random [angular speeds](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=39) for the dice.
- Then, find the [trajectory](http://projects.forum.nokia.com/gles2phys) for each and when touching a border.
- [Bounce them](https://projects.forum.nokia.com/gles2phys/files) to one direction or another depending on the rotation at that particular moment.
- Change the sign of the angular speed if the dice bounce back.
- Reduce the speed about 50% each bounce, until a threshold.
- Below that threshold, leave them in the floor and stop movement.

Comment: some of your links do not work