# Developing a 3D game on Android platform with Bullet physics engine

Tags: android, 3d, android-ndk

I want to develop a 3D game with a simple physics engine using Bullet. However Bullet was written in C++, so I propose to build it with ndk, and use the dynamic library to create my 3D physics world. I am unsure, precisely, how to approach this. Explicit examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [Bullet on Android with the NDK](http://apistudios.com/hosted/marzec/badlogic/wordpress/?p=248)?

It is a wrapper for Bullet. I haven't used it myself so I can't say more but it might be a good place to start, so you don't have to wrap it yourself.

I found it after a quick search from [Best games/physics engines to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676742/best-games-physics-engines-to-use)

Other interesting pages

- [android physics engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417526/android-physics-engine)
- [Are there any decent physics engines for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034253/are-there-any-decent-physics-engines-for-android)
- [Ideas for physics for rolling dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004381/ideas-for-physics-for-rolling-dice)

Answer (score 3):

Libgdx has now incorporated Bullet. http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2640